# CakePHP redirect loop

Tags: cakephp, redirect

I'm having the weirdest Cake error with my code. When the code below calls the add() method (also reproduced here and from a different controller), the code redirects him back with a 302 found HTTP code to the edit() action (in essence, to the user it appears as if nothing happens). To further complicate matters, when I call the same URL when I'm not on that page (despite the pages not being reliant on each other), I get redirected to the base of my app, which results in a redirect loop. I tried calling other methods from this controller (with their proper arguments) to see if this was just a problem with the add() action, but I get the same redirect loop. I've already checked all over SE but cannot find a relevant answer.

Here is the relevant code:

```
function edit($id=null) {
 if(!$id) {
    $this->Session->setFlash('Invalid!');
    $this->redirect(array(
        'action' => 'index')
        );

 }
 else {
     //Get the slides themselves
    $slides = $this->Slide->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Slide.module_id' => $id)));
    $this->set('slides', $slides);
    //Get the data for the Module
    $module = $this->Module->find('first',
            array(
                'conditions' => array (
                    'Module.id' => $id
                ),
                'fields' => array(
                    'Module.module_name',
                    'Module.id')
            )
        );
 }
 }
```

And here is the add() code (again, from a different module):

```
    function add($module = null) {
        if ($this->request->is('get')) {
                        //Set some variables for the view (this code I know works as it has been used successfully elsewhere
        } 
        else { //User is POSTing
        $this->Slide->create();
        $this->Slide->save($this->data);
        }
    }
```

Thanks to everyone in advance; I couldn't do this without your support!

EDIT: Here is the AppController code:

```
public $components = array(
    'Auth' => array(
        'authorize' => array(
            'Actions' => array('actionPath' => 'controllers')
            ),
    'loginAction' => array(
        'controller' => 'users',
        'action' => 'login'
        ),
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'fields' => array('username' => 'email')
             )
        ),
    'logoutRedirect' => array('/')          
    ),
    'Session'
);
public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Session');
public function isAuthorized() {
    return true;
}
public function Controller() {

}
```

}

Comment: What is in your app controller?

Comment: Just my helpers and components. I'll post them if you think it will help. It might be worth noting that my two other controllers work fine.

Comment: I ask because, usually when I find that everything else is routing fine and then I get a redirect issue, It's because I have put a condition in my beforeFilter. If you feel there is no problem there then we may need more code. Nothing sticks out in your relevant code.

Comment: I don't have a beforeFilter() in the controller, and there are no routing lines in the AppController. I'll edit the post and include the AppController code. Let me know if you need any more code.

Comment: Could be an Auth problem, trying to redirect you away because access to the action isn't allowed?

Comment: Its permitted in ACL, how would I ensure that Auth was allowing me?

Comment: You should try to disable the APC caching. I have the same weird issues on debian server where APC is enabled in /core/config.php

Comment: I just figured it out. I set my beforeFilter() to allow the method, then tried to access it without logging in. When I did that, the errors started to appear. Turns out the code in some of my helpers is screwed up. Thanks to everyone for helping!

Comment: Super old question, but it's the top one on Google, so I thought I'd add what fixed my problem here: `parent::beforeFilter();`.